# To sync a desktop wiki software with a MediaWiki wiki

Tags: gratis, wiki, mediawiki, wikimedia

Is there a desktop wiki software that can be sync on a MediaWiki wiki (private)?

I have my own wiki, hosted in a wikifarm, and I was wondering if I could use a desktop wiki software as a local editor.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's desktop software for offline reading ([Kiwix](https://www.kiwix.org/en/) most notably) but none for offline editing. It's a hard problem because the editor would have to know about lots of "secondary" pages (templates and the like) to be able to edit the primary page in any useful way.

Comment: But some bots could be used to edit remotely wiki pages, don't they? And for "simple" page?

Comment: There are plenty of automated editing tools, sure, but I don't think that's what you are asking. Also a couple of hacks to open a wiki page for editing (while online) in a text editor, Emacs, etc.

Comment: What are the hacks? (just to know, it's not my question, but it could be useful to know). My question is more about to be able to work offline, and sync everything at once on the internet host.

Comment: The Wikipedia page [Help:Text editor support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Text_editor_support) lists a lot of them. (Also apparently there's something called [Offline MediaWiki Code Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools/Editing_tools#Offline_MediaWiki_Code_Editor)? I haven't heard about it before.)